# Hibernate: No type name

Tags: hibernate

Hello I am using Hibernate 3.6 with XML mapping (no annotations).

I tried to create instance of [Configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/), but it failed. The only message Hibernate told me was this:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: No type name
```

**Yep, that's it**. No mapping file name, no entity name, nothing. I am pretty much desperate here, I really have no idea what to do. Maybe there are more options to put in `hibernate.cfg.xml`, maybe some advanced logging.

Do you have an idea how to deal with this? Getting more info about this exception or making Hibernate to be more chatty would be great. Thanks

Comment: The reference documentation has a section about the way to configure logging: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#configuration-logging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [this unresolved bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3210) against hibernate-core that looks like what you're experiencing. You can check the link there to see the source code where the exception is being thrown. If you put a breakpoint at the line where the exception is thrown, you can probably gather enough information from the debugger to see where the problem is. Otherwise, if you can localize the problem and post some mappings, someone might be able to spot the problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have not set the type property in your hibernate mapping file.

```
<map name="answers" table="anskk" cascade="all">
<key column="qid"></key>
<index column="answer" type="string"></index>
<many-to-many class="com.kk.beans.User" column="userid"></many-to-many></map>
```

here type="string" is for index in map
hope it helps